# Promise working without resolving it in protractor

Tags: protractor

The below is my page object code

```
this.getRowBasedOnName = function (name) {
    return this.tableRows.filter(function (elem, index) {
        return elem.element(by.className('ng-binding')).getText().then(function (text) {
            return text.toUpperCase().substring(0, 1) === name.toUpperCase().substring(0, 1);
        });
    });
};
```

the above function is called in the same page object in another function, which is

```
this.clickAllProductInProgramTypeBasedOnName = function (name) {
   this.getRowBasedOnName(name).then(function (requiredRow) {
        requiredRow.all(by.tagName('label')).get(1).click();
    });
};
```

but the above code throws an error in the console as **requiredRow.all** is not a function

but when i do the following :

```
this.clickAllProductInProgramTypeBasedOnName = function (name) {
    var row = this.getRowBasedOnName(name)
    row.all(by.tagName('label')).get(1).click();
};
```

this works fine and clicks the required element.

But **this.getRowBasedOnName()** function returns a promise, which should and can be used after resolving it uisng **then function**. How come it is able to work by just assigning it to a variable?

Comment: Your method `this.getRowBasedOnName(name)` returns a promise augmented with the methods of a web element (`ElementArrayFinder`). A call on these methods will chaine a new promise. So in the first case you are handling a promise and in the second you are handling the result of the promise which is an array.

Answer (score 2):

When you resolve the result of `getRowBasedOnName()`, which is an `ElementArrayFinder`, you get a *regular array of elements* which does not have an `all()` method.

You don't need to resolve the result of `getRowBasedOnName()` at all - let it be an `ElementArrayFinder` which you can chain with `all()` as in your second sample:

```
var row = this.getRowBasedOnName(name);
row.all(by.tagName('label')).get(1).click();
```

In other words, `requiredRow` is not an `ElementArrayFinder`, but `row` is.